# Analytic vs Dialectic logic

Tags: kant, idealism, dialectic, german-philosophy

What are analytic and dialectic logic in Kantian philosophy? What's the difference between them and why can't we use analytic logic as an organon?

Comment: See [Kant](https://iep.utm.edu/kantview/#H2) and [Immanuel Kant: Logic](https://iep.utm.edu/k-logic/) and

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the meaning of "dialectic" and "analytic" in Kant's First Critique?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/86303/what-is-the-meaning-of-dialectic-in-kants-first-critique)